# mobile.changepage requiring page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using $.mobile.ChangePage() to navigate from one HTML page to another. But the contents of the page is not changing. while doing so the page URL changes but the new page is not loaded. it requires to be refreshed to load.

Comment: I'm using this function to navigate to the "details-page"
 function next_page()
        {
            $.mobile.changePage("details-page.html", {transition:"slide"});
        }

And this is my HTML
<a href="#" onclick="next_page();">Details</a>

Answer (score 0):

you should use JavaScript function to change the page..using

```
window.location = 'your page ';
```

hope it will resolve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you provided in the comments above, you are likely getting an error stating that `next_page` is not defined. Given that you are dealing with jQuery Mobile, try assigning the `click` handler slightly differently:

Change the definition of the link to something like this:

```
<a id="btnNextPage" href="#" >Details</a>
```

You don't have to give it an `id` - you could just use selectors to identify the link in the following javascript:

```
 // the event handler
 function next_page() { 
     $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com", {transition:"slide"}); 
 }

// assign the click event when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
      $("#btnNextPage").click ( next_page );
});
```